# When installing a newer/existing version of an App, SQLite database gets created instead of reuse

Tags: android, database, sqlite

When installing a newer/existing version of an App,  SQLite database gets created instead of reuse - the existing database vanishes.

Here is how my classes are

`class HDDBAdapter {

         int DB_LOCA_VERSION = 1;

             HDDBOpenHelper hdHelper;`

```
  HDDBAdapter(_ctxt) {  
        hdHelper = new HDDBOpenHelper(_ctxt, "mydb.db", null, DB_LOCA_VERSION);  
  }  

  open() {
     try {
       db =hdHelper.getWritableDatabase();
     }
     catch ...
  }


static class HDDBOpenHelper extends SQLiteopenHelper {
   public HunyDewDBOpenHelper(Context ct, String n, CursorFactory cf, int v) {
        super(ct, n, cf, vv);
    }

  private static final String DB_CREATE_BOX = "create table " + "mydb.db" + "("
        + ... + ");";

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
        arg0.setVersion(DB_LOCA_VERSION);
        arg0.execSQL(DB_CREATE_BOX);
    }

    public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onOpen(db);
    }
```

}

The first time I run the application - the application creates a database with my inputs. Then I load a newer version of the application -  `DB_LOCA_VERSION`  stays the same. In the newer version it is the logic not related to database that was changed.

So I first "Force stop" the application  ("Clear Data" is not performed) and then uninstall the App. Now I run the newer version - this newer version does not use the existing database - it creates a new one. Why is that? I want to use the existing database. Please let me know if I am missing something here. Any clues/pointers/questions will be helpful.

When I install it apparently fails inside  `getWritableDatabase` , so -  `onCreate`  gets called first - before  `onOpen` . Please note the constructor for  `HDDBAdapter` is unchanged across the app versions - so shouldn't it get the  `hdHelper`  for the existing **"mydb.db"**? And not have  `getWritableDatabase`  cause  `onCreate`  to get invoked.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So I first "Force stop" the application ("Clear Data" is not performed) and then uninstall the App. Now I run the newer version - this newer version does not use the existing database - it creates a new one. Why is that?

Because when you uninstall an app, all databases for that app will be deleted.

Comment: OK - I thought only explicit "Clear data" removes the database :-( Thank you for pointing it out.  So how do I uninstall the app to install the new app and not delete the existing database?

Comment: maybe I should ask it as a new question??

Comment: Why don't just reinstall the app?

Comment: how do you reinstall the app?

Comment: I mean I can do adb install -r during development, but how do I do reinstall  in the field? Thanks

Comment: It depends... if you are developing a serious app, you will submit to the Android Market. There, users can install an app, and when there's a new version the app will be reinstalled. On the other hand, if you just distribute the APK of your app... once it's installed, it will be reinstalled if the user try to install a new version of the APK.

Comment: No thats not true. I currently have the issue that even when I clear my app data and install a new version, the old database remains. Also usually the database is not deleted, you can test it when installing some apps from the Google Play Store

Answer (score 0):

One option is to change the db files to sdcard or some other folders during uninstallation and
bring it back once new app is installed.